# SELECT statement that only shows rows where there is a NULL in a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got an issue I've been racking my brain on this and the code I have makes sense to me but still doesn't work.

Here is the question:

> Give me a list of the names of all the unused (potential) caretakers and the names and types of all unclaimed pieces of art (art that does not yet have a caretaker).

Here is how the tables are set up:

- `CareTakers`: `CareTakerID, CareTakerName`
- `Donations`: `DonationID, DonorID, DonatedMoney, ArtName, ArtType, ArtAppraisedPrice, ArtLocationBuilding, ArtLocationRoom, CareTakerID`
- `Donors`: `DonorID, DonorName, DonorAddress`

Here is the code I have:

```
SELECT 
    CareTakerName, ArtName, ArtType
FROM 
    CareTakers 
JOIN 
    Donations ON CareTakers.CareTakerID = Donations.CareTakerID
WHERE 
    Donations.CareTakerID = ''
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: You are trying to join on CareTakerID, but if art does not have a caretaker, then there will not be a CareTakerID, right?

Comment: That's correct. What they're wanting is a Column that shows the Names of CareTakers that have not been used, and they want the artName and the ArtTypes that do not have a CareTakeID assigned to them.

Comment: This is going to be tough with 1 query. The results from the left table will not be aligned with the right table, and you can have a different number of results from each table. I would suggest using two queries and just showing a side-by-side in Excel (if that is a possibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two queries for the reasons I noted in my comment on the OP above... However, since you requested one query, the following should get you what you asked for, although the result sets are not depicted side-by-side.

```
SELECT 
    CareTakerName, ArtName, ArtType
FROM 
    CareTakers 
LEFT JOIN 
    Donations ON CareTakers.CareTakerID = Donations.CareTakerID
WHERE 
    NULLIF(Donations.CareTakerID,'') IS NULL
UNION    -- Returns a stacked result set
SELECT 
    CareTakerName, ArtName, ArtType
FROM 
    CareTakers 
RIGHT JOIN 
    Donations ON CareTakers.CareTakerID = Donations.CareTakerID
WHERE 
    NULLIF(CareTakers.CareTakerID,'') IS NULL
```

If this is not sufficient, I can supply two separate queries as I suggested above.

*EDIT: Included NULLIF with '' criteria to treat blank and NULL equally in the where clause.

Comment: man that was is pretty close. but it's leaving out some stuff. It's got one of art names and one of the art types that don't have a caretaker assigned to them. but there is another ArtName and ArtType that does not have a caretaker assigned to it

Comment: It sounds like you may have a mix of some blank and NULL values in the join criteria. For the ArtName and ArtType that are not showing up - verify that the CareTakerID field is not BLANK. Optionally, I have modified the query above to take this into consideration. Try to run it again and post your results.

Answer (score 1):

`Donations.CareTakerID = ''` is not the same as testing for `NULL`. That's testing for an empty string.

You want

```
Donations.CareTakerID is NULL
```

Also note that

```
Donations.CaretakerID = NULL
```

will not give you what you want either (a common mistake.)

Comment: The original query is doing an implicit `INNER JOIN` so there will be no records where `Donations.CareTakerID is NULL`

Answer (score 1):

Use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT CareTakerName, ArtName, ArtType
FROM CareTakers
LEFT JOIN Donations ON CareTakers.CareTakerID = Donations.CareTakerID
WHERE Donations.CareTakerID IS NULL
```

Comment: This is really close, but for ArtName and ArtType it's showing null, I need to also see what ArtName and what ArtType also does not have a CareTaker assigned to them.

Comment: This is only half of the request - CareTakers who do not have art. A similar query is needed for the other half - Art with no caretaker.

Comment: could I do the second part as a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, You need to know What is a *NULL* value. Is it zero, blank space or something else? The answer is: **No**.

*NULL* is not a value, it only means that a value wasn't provided when the row was created.

```
SELECT d.ArtName, d.ArtType
,(SELECT CareTakerName FROM CareTakers c WHERE c.CareTakerID = d.CareTakerID)CareTakerName
FROM Donations d
WHERE ISNULL(d.CareTakerID, 0) = 0
```

*I like to use a "default" value for a NULL column

More infotmation here: [SQL NULL Values](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp)

Comment: Using the SELECT * gives me more columns than I'm needing. I only need CareTakerName, ArtName, and ArtType.

Comment: Come on !! jfritts6524 just write the name of your columns. I mean Instead "*" write the name of your columns